# jelastic JSF 2 PrimeFaces 4 Glassfish 4

Tags: cloud, jelastic

My JSF 2.2 + PrimeFaces 4 web application is running correctly on local Glassfish 4 , but when I was uploading  war file of the application to Jelastic dogado using Glassfish 3.1.2.2 ,MySQL,and Maven 3 , my application does not recognize jsf tags because Glassfish 3.1.2.2 does not know JSF 2.2 ,please help me how can I solve this problem using Jelastic Dogado cloud platform

Answer (score 1):

Also, JSF for Glassfish could be updated from 2.1 to 2.2, I have reproduced this workaround: http://blog.eisele.net/2013/01/testdriving-mojarra-220-m08-on.html, everything worked fine for me.
To perform this manipulation you need install FTP to your environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the VDS and install GlassFish 4 onto it manually.

Comment: Yes,it may be one solution for my problem.But I just want to learn,is there any solution for that problem.Also thanks for your attention.

Comment: Unfortunately this is the only way to run GlassFish 4 on Jelastic at the moment.

If you are running it successfully locally. It would be quite similar to install it on a Jelastic VDS and get it all working there.